# Column 80 - Plain Text optimised Stack Exchange

Tags: app

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Column 80]

### About

Browsing the existing Stack Exchange family of websites was *OK* in a text-based browser, but when you're stuck in a Linux shell with no way out and no other computers around and you just **know** you saw the answer on Server Fault last week, this is how you can find it easily.

It assumes you already have existing knowledge of the SE family of sites in order to navigate.

#### License

Public Domain. Feel free to do with it what you will. [Grab it here](http://www.column80.com/Column80v1.0.zip) (note: This is the old v1 API. I have not packaged v2 yet).

#### Access

<strike>http://www.column80.com (note: looks like rubbish in modern browsers, Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, etc. It has got to be viewed in Lynx to get the full effect).</strike> offline as of late 2019 due to virtually no traffic over the past 10 years.

#### Platform

Optimised for Lynx. This sounded pretty niche when I made it, [but it looks like it might already have been some use to some users](http://hack.org/lists/mosig/msg02320.html)!

### Contact

Leave some feedback in this question.

### Code

I haven't done any programming in about five years, so it was also a way for me refresh my skills. It uses the [PHPStack](https://stackapps.com/questions/319) by [Thomas McDonald](https://stackapps.com/users/1031/thomas-mcdonald). <sub><s>If you *really* want the source and you promise not to make (public) fun of me, then I'd be more than happy to share.</s></sub> I've cleaned up the code a bit, and incorporated some suggestions from the public, so I feel comfortable releasing the code. [Grab it here](http://www.column80.com/Column80.zip).

- (10th Jun 2010) now updated to incorporate the unannounced API changes
- (25th Jun 2010) changed front page to retrieve data from StackAuth, and changed URL format to prepare for URL Rewriting ([using stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php))
- (11th Jul 2010) now updated to work with the v1.0 API (the list of [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/about) sites is looking healthy!)
- (9th May 2014) updated the site to use the v2 of the API. Removed some never-used features such as tag search and user profiles, as I'm pretty short on time.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging the console-lovers and treating them to this!

Comment: ...and for mentioning Lynx :)

Comment: +1 And it does look OK in Chrome. The only issue I saw was long unwrapped lines, which makes sense when optimising for a text-based browser.

Comment: @Mark, one of my plans for down the track is to wrap words nicely at 80 columns which will fix that, and make it look OK in modern browsers as well (thank God for the `<pre>` tag)

Comment: Yay, something useful came about as a result of my creations.
What are you using for the search, considering that was the only method I haven't quite figured out the best way to do?

Comment: @Thomas, I used your search function out-of-the-box. It worked quite well, because the API requires the use of the options rather than a string, so I found it worked just fine.

Comment: Since you are using PHP, you could just use the wordwrap function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php , no need for any pre tags me thinks?

Comment: @SeanJA, Good idea, thanks. I'll get that implemented sometime today.

Comment: @SeanJA, thanks I've done the word wrapping. It looks better in modern browsers now.

Comment: Nice idea! Have you tried it with HTML tables though? I've had good experiences with their rendering in lynx

Comment: What are the "unannounced changes" you mention?

Comment: @Russel_h - no need for HTML Tables, as Lynx displays the HTML just fine in its current form, Lynx tables are only good for tabular data (like a spreadsheet, which is really what Tables were designed for in the first place).

Comment: @George, I'm referring to the removal of the `answers` from the `questions` query. I had to use SODiff (http://stackapps.com/questions/631/) to spot the change. I'm guessing it was probably mentioned in some question somewhere but I don't have the time or energy to read and track every single topic on StackApps. I might have been a bit harsh though because I was having a bad day - my son had been crying for three hours straight and I couldn't get him to sleep and then he pooped on me.

Comment: @Far: It's okay. I missed that one too. I even asked a question about it :)

Comment: And for an excellent first search, try "80 column limit" :)

Comment: Just tried it in Lynx itself - works like a charm. One piece of advice - links to other questions in posts should probably be rewritten - like what I've done in my [mobile site](http://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone).

Comment: @George, yeah I need to update it to support the stackauth API endpoints as well so that could be a good oppertunity to put rewriting in.

Comment: The link to return home doesn't work.

Comment: You might want to add Links to the list of "allowed browsers" or it might feel left out :-)

Comment: When I try to [view a question](http://sa.column80.com/?q=476), I get an error.

Comment: @Simon - thanks. One of the MySQL databases went over its size quota, should all work now.

Comment: Also: http://sa.column80.com/?s=hr&t=intitle

Comment: @Simon - unfortunately I had to change the system to run on cookies, so once the cookies have expired you'll need to go back to column80.com and start again

Comment: I meant the <hr> tags in question titles being rendered.

Comment: I do intend to be writing a lua and python port of this project. Can I have your permission to do so?

Comment: Absolutally - Go for it :)

Comment: Thanks. These will be clients rather than online, and I might depending on how it goes hack answering into it.

Comment: If you want to save a bit of time, feel free to grab the source code and abuse it as much as you like

Comment: Why you'd be so addicted to SE to use this heavily is beyond me.

Comment: @muntoo - if you read the description, it's not about being addicted, it's about being stuck in a console session with no other options and you still need to get access to Server Fault.

Comment: Reminds me of the DOS version of Pegasus Mail in the 90s - a staple in Netware environments.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Did the job great on the kindle browser when I was in a bit of a squeeze the other day

Comment: This is soooo cool! I didn't know about Lynx. Thanks for this very cool applications!

Comment: Is it possible answer/ask with this code somehow? I am not yet comforbtable in using Lynx to download the codes in questions for fast edition, is there any good videos or some help things for this? This may when used correctly to speed up things and kill nasty procrastination, ideas how?

Comment: @hhh - no. The API does not expose these methods, not even the v2.0 API.

Comment: I wish I could use this with Vim, ideas how to use this fast with Vim?  It gets killed to the Warning msg?!

Comment: @hhh - you can bypass the warning message, there's a link that says "I'm not going to stop you" - or, use this URL: http://www.column80.com/index.php?continue=y

Comment: @MarkHenderson You've rescued me through a half-working Ubuntu recovery mode. Thanks. Although, I'd love if the API wasn't read-only. :-(

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS - glad I could be of assistance. I haven't touched the v2 API yet (figured there wasn't anything of value for this app to be added, plus their online authentication isn't text mode friendly). But if it ever becomes read-write I will update it :)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison *mentioning* Lynx? Lynx is *the* browser! (even if I have to admit that I tend to use just `links`)

Comment: I might stop using SE in a graphical browser! It's so satisfying.....

Comment: I think you meant to release it under "Public Domain" instead of "No license".  "No license" means full copyright protection, and nobody can use it.

Comment: You might want to remove the "you're not using lynx" banner for xlinks2 users.

Comment: @thejh - do you have a useragent string I can check against?

Comment: My useragent string is "Links (2.7; Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae i686; GNU C 4.7; x)", so maybe check for "Links .*" or so?

Comment: _Public domain_?! Wow. That's extreme. Awesome work!

Comment: @Jop - honestly, it's because I have no interest in maintaining it or updating it, so I may as well let it free into the world so people can do as they wish with it.

Comment: @PerWiklander - well better late than never. Links is on the whitelist for browsers :)

Answer (score 32):

Just wanted to give you a heads-up...

One of the questions contained `<button>` in the title, causing the entire rest of the page to be rendered in a button. You might want to run the title through `htmlentities()` first.

Comment: Ooh, thanks. Do you know what the site & question ID is? I'll try it out in Lynx to see if it screws up on there.

Comment: @Farseeker: Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563753/why-insert-double-span-tag-in-button

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is enough, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it is. that escapes all dangerous characters

Comment: Yes, but it seems to not show the \<span\> at all in the title now. Also, the button looks like "\<submit\>"(Screenshot here: http://imgur.com/EUzzA), also happens in listing.

Comment: @MarkHenderson FUBAR is an adjective(Especially the first word) so your comment should read "Yep, it's also FUBAR[or FUBARed] in Lynx."

Answer (score 11):

This is nice, but it gives the "You're not using Lynx" warning for other text-based browsers. It looks and works great in w3m as well, so it should probably skip the warning in that browser as well.

Answer (score 8):

Just pointing out: this system actually violates the content license because it does not link back to the original posts or authors in any way on the questions.

[From the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/):

> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
>
>    *Yes*
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
>
>    *No*
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
>
>    *Yes*
> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
>    *No*

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if this applies to remixes from the API, but I guess I can comply. Not entirely sure how useful linking to the originals will be from a plain text browser, but oh well.

Comment: @Sally Thanks. I had forgotten about this. Ironically for years I did comply with the license but I had to make some changes a few years ago and I suspect I undid the attribution requirements. The source code for this site is, honestly, probably lost. I will see if I can dig it up to make it compliant.

Answer (score 4):

Searching with empty string (`http://www.column80.com/api.v2.php?a=stackoverflow&s=`) gives error:

> ```
> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error 400: An API error has occurred.
>   thrown in /home3/markness/column80.com/stackphp/src/api.php on line 284
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I've got some stuff I've gotta do on the site in the near future, so I'll address this then.

Answer (score 2):

Nice but is there a nice url we can remember that goes straight to:

http://sa.column80.com/?api=0 maybe?

It would be nice to have the search button BEFORE the title and tag options.

Also I get bugged about cookies, do you really need cookies?

Comment: Honestly, I hardly remember how this little app works. It might be time for a refresh. The cookies were from memory from an earlier revision that must not have been taken out.

Comment: Cookies are gone, URl structure has been changed.

Comment: Nice. The search is a bit hit or miss though. (E.g: it's order dependent) Have you considered using Google or Bing?

Comment: I am just using the built-in Stack Exchange search. I believe it's a full string search, but not entirely sure. Problem with google search is that it will redirect you to the full SE site, not my Column 80 one. That might be OK, it might not be.

Comment: It looks like it's possible to extract the question number from the URL.