# OBSOLETE - SOAPI-DIFF: Your app broke? Check SOAPI-DIFF to find out what changed in the API

Tags: app, obsolete, dev-tool

## OBSOLETE - the website soapi.info is down.

### [SOAPI-DIFF](http://soapi.info/Tools/Diff.aspx)

Soothe your beta api blues with a DIFF view of the entire API compared to the last changed version.

Instantly identify added/removed/changed elements of the API.

e.g.

Added:
[image]
<sub>(source: [soapi.info](http://soapi.info/images/diff-added.png))</sub>

Changed:

[alt text](http://soapi.info/images/diff-changed.png)

[**SOAPI-DIFF**](http://soapi.info/Tools/Diff.aspx) can be found @ http://soapi.info/Tools/Diff.aspx

Changes to the API are detected and reported within 4 hours of change.  To be notified of API changes, follow [SOAPIWATCH](http://twitter.com/soapiwatch) on Twitter

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest two enhancements. One would be a character in a status column to indicate changed entries. This would make in-page searches easier. Perhaps "+", "-" and "C" adjacent to the line number.

```
...
C00054    pagesize ... 2,147,483,647])    C00054    pagesize ... 100])
...
-09137    saber-tooth tiger                         ____________________________
...
          ____________________________    +09374    unicorn
...
 09839    same-old-feature                 09839    same-old-feature
```

The second would be a collapsed view, that would show only the changes (along with the route, parameter and returns headers that they fall under).

Perhaps at `soapi.info/Tools/Diff-summary.aspx`.

Comment: ++ i have  been trying to come up with a compact diff summary format suitable for email/rss. this sounds like a viable starting point.