# Answers suddenly not getting returned.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Try:

http://api.stackapps.com/0.8/questions/212

None of the answers are present.

Comment: Might I recommend [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/631/soapi-diff-your-app-broke-check-soapi-diff-to-find-out-what-changed-in-the-api)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `answers` parameter.

[Docs](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions)

Comment: Guess I kinda missed that :)

Answer (score 2):

Answers changed to be off by default:

[Don't include answers in question lists by default](https://stackapps.com/questions/613/dont-include-answers-in-question-lists-by-default)