# OBSOLETE - StackImage 2 - Create Your Own Unique Custom Flair!

Tags: app, website, obsolete

### Examples

http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/4dd2fde77a2ca/stackoverflow/193619
http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/4dd3772eb3ae6/cooking.stackexchange/60
http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/4dd750ae03743/askubuntu/235
http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/4dd339baac363/math.stackexchange/232

### About

StackImage 2 is the successor to [StackImage](https://stackapps.com/questions/847/stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users-now-with-global-flair) - but it is anything *but* an incremental update. StackImage 2 allows you to design your very own unique custom flair from scratch. Just how customizable is StackImage 2? Well, you can...

- Set the size of the flair (both width and height)
- Set the background-color and border color as well as the width of the border
- Add any item from your profile to your flair (except 'about me')
- Set the font, font style, size, and color of each item
- Set the size of your Gravatar and the site icon
- Preview the flair with your own account information

To design your flair, simply use the interactive tool to drag-and-drop the components you want onto your flair. You can then move the items around and resize them.

Once you're done, just click 'save' and decide between pre-generated HTML code and a JPG image that you can embed on forums / etc. Both will stay up to date with your account.

**Note:** this tool is still under development, so please feel free to post any bugs you find or features you'd like to see. Keep your eyes peeled for new features.

#### License

Closed source.

#### Download

http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/

#### Platform

Tested on Chrome 11, Firefox 4, and IE 9 - but it should work in any standards-compliant browser

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

JavaScript (with jQuery) and PHP on the server.

Comment: Mmmm, closed source... :-(

Comment: @jme: Well... the client side portion of the application is obviously not closed source - you can see how the editor works and the calls to the server that it makes. I am *considering* releasing the source code for the image-generating portion of the source code.

Comment: :( requires a login/password otherwise it's awesome

Comment: @austinbv: The login / password is required so that StackImage 2 can store the information about the flair you create. Otherwise it would need to be passed as a query string parameter... which is unfeasible.

Comment: SE sites don't require passwords and allow using other authentication systems.  It'd be nice if this service followed suit.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I am currently in the process of unifying the accounts on all of my web applications, so at least there will only be a single name / password to remember. The reason I need authentication is because the tool needs to store a lot of information for each flair instance - more than I could fit in the query string of a URL. Therefore, to facilitate the storage and to eventually (though not yet implemented) allow for editing instances, authentication is required.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Sure, but it'd be nice if you didn't require *password*-based authentication and instead allowed using, say, OpenID or Google.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Ah, I get it. Well, depending on how things go, that may end up being a possibility.

Comment: url is broken , stackimage and stackimage2 both doesnt work

Comment: Could not get it... url is still broken