# StackMail - Making the StackExchange Sites Accessible Via Email

Tags: app, php, email

> ### Planned Obsolescence
>
> Due to almost negligible usage and ongoing maintenance issues, I would  like to announce that the StackMail service will be shut down in a few days.

### Screenshot

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackmail.png

### About

StackMail is an email-based web service for the StackExchange sites. The concept is simple: send an email to `stackmail@quickmediasolutions.com` with one of the commands as the subject line - and presto! You will receive a reply with the results.

If you just want a demonstration, (and I'm sure you do) send the following as the subject line:

```
help
```

...and you will receive a reply with the list of commands and what they do. Some more ideas:

```
stats meta
user 18 stackapps
questions serverfault
```

Eventually, as more methods are added, you will be able to search for questions, users, etc.

#### License

*Closed-source.*

#### Download

*N/A*

#### Platform

Any email client that can send and receive text-based email.

### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Code

Yet another application that uses my [stack.PHP wrapper](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php).

Comment: Very nice; however, I don't imagine I will be using StackMail a lot unless I'm in a situation where I can only use email...

Comment: Also, are all of those examples supposed to be sent through the subject line? Furthermore, what happens if I include something in the message body?

Comment: @Maxim: Yes, all examples go into the subject line. The body of the message is ignored. As for using this, my idea is that it would be great for someone who only has access to a cellphone / smartphone and wants something quick. On some networks, this can even be done through text messaging.

Comment: sup @George - got just one question: can this be used for instant and/or automated email notifications? using e-mail as a request basis is completely against all reasons I wanted to use e-mails at first! :o

Comment: @Cawas: Unfortunately not right now. If this feature is deemed important, I might consider adding it.

Comment: to me it's fundamental. I still find it almost unconceivable that so many educated people overlook e-mail this much.

Comment: @Cawas: Fair enough. I'll see what I can do. Bear in mind that this service, when I create it, will be limited in the amount of email it sends / receives. After all, I don't want my domain put on a blacklist for bulk emailing.

Comment: George, that sounds fantastic! to me that service don't need to receive anything but that wouldn't help on the blacklisting issue at all.

Comment: @Cawas: It will take a bit of work to get this working for a large number of people, but it would be great if you would be willing to test it. Please send me an email at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com` and I'll try to get back to you within a day or two.

Comment: @George done deal. ;)

Comment: @Cawas: You should receive an email within an hour or so. It's not complete yet, but it will give you an idea of how it will look.

Comment: @George it looks pretty good. Hope the final version comes soon! :) I have also tried google's feedburner or something, but not only takes a while to configure - I still haven't received any emails other than confirming I was registered to receive them.

Comment: @Cawas: Okay. I've finished most of it now. You can find it here: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stackmail/ After registering, select the 'Recent Comments' feed, fill in the details, and click 'Subscribe'.

Comment: I'd like to say just "hey that's amazing!" because it truly is to me. I couldn't ever code it that fast! But... The last digest I've got in Sep 25 comes with too much info and I can't find most of those comments unless I search individually for each. Do you think it would be too hard to add a link to them? :P

Comment: @Cawas: I certainly could. And the reason I created it so fast was because I used CakePHP.

Comment: @George heard of it. Now I'm more interested in trying it. :)

Comment: I don't know where else to report this, but I'm receiving completly wrong daily digests. I did register for two, but none seem to be working. One comes with **RJFalconer** from `users/28411/mentioned` (that should be me on superuser) and the other one comes empty from `users/143411/mentioned` (no idea where that code came from, I've registered *274502* for SO).

Comment: @Cawas: Okay, I'll investigate this.

Comment: @Cawas: I manually fixed this. Tomorrow you should get the proper feed.

Comment: @George two observations from all this time (since my last comment): (1) I'm getting two emails now, for quite a while. (2) they come every day, even if there's nothing new. so I get a lot of repetition again. :P

Comment: @Cawas: Thanks for letting me know. I'll see what I can do and I'll check the database to see why you're getting two of them. Eventually, I'd like to only send off an email if there is new content like you mentioned.

Comment: @george if you haven't, you really should consider using github and or google code for tickets such as this. ;)

Comment: @Cawas: Well, for most of my other projects, I have used Launchpad.

Comment: @George launchpad is great... why don't you use it for all your projects?

Comment: @Cawas: I use it for all of my code-hosting. This particular project isn't actually open-source at the moment.

Comment: @George refrain the first (1) observation. I actually get two emails from two different sources. So that's not actually a bug... It's just really annoying due to the second (2) observation! :P