# StackStatus - Monitor the status of the Stack Exchange API

Tags: app, stack.php, status

> ### Note:
>
> This service is temporarily offline. The original version was having some problems, and I am also migrating a number of tools from PHP to Python - so expect to see this tool come back to life further down the road as time permits.

### Live Status Image

http://stackstatus.quickmediasolutions.com/

### About

StackStatus is a small image-based status tool for monitoring the Stack Exchange API. It polls each of the API routes every 24 hours and records any failures or unexpected results. The image above is updated accordingly to indicate the current and recent status of the API.

#### License

*Closed source*

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

### Code

The image-generating portion is written in PHP using [GD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library). The API polling code is also written in PHP and uses [stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php-now-with-v1-1-support).

Comment: Congrats on the mod upgrade :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks broken. Last check was 23th February and it looks there's something wrong in your checking algorithm.

Comment: Yes, StackStatus is currently being replaced by the [Stack.PHP test suite](http://stackphp.quickmediasolutions.com/tests/results.html) which is *far* more comprehensive and generates much more information. Because StackStatus was tying up server resources, it was retired from use on Feb. 23.

Comment: @George and wouldn't it be better to annouce it in your question?

Comment: It would - but I've been very busy (with the contest and everything) so I haven't got around to it yet.