# /questions/{id}/linked is failing for this question on ServerFault.

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions

This route is reporting an error:

http://api.serverfault.com/1.1/questions/45734/linked

---

Incidentally, I discovered this error thanks to my handy tool [StackStatus](https://stackapps.com/questions/2124/stackstatus-monitor-the-status-of-the-stackexchange-api), which runs a status check on the API every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bit of fun with closed questions today, which was probably causing this.

It should be fixed.