# Stack.JS - Powerful Event-driven Library for Accessing the Stack Exchange API in JavaScript.

Tags: library, api-v2, javascript

[image]

### About

Stack.JS is the JavaScript equivalent of [Stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/q/826) and aims to replicate the request structure of that library as much as possible. The library is still a long ways from being complete but is functional at this point. As was the case with Stack.PHP, Stack.JS is 100% fully documented and comes with a test suite to make sure the library functions as documented.

Request throttling was just added and there are plans to implement a cache.

### Code Snippet

```
var site = API.Site('stackapps');

var response = site.Questions([1, 2, 3]).SortBy('creation_date').Exec();

response.Fetch(function(data) {

    for(var i=0; i<data['items'].length; ++i)
        console.log(data['items'][i]['title']);

});
```

### License

Stack.JS (like Stack.PHP) is released under [the MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

### Download

You will need to check out the code from the repository (see below) until an official release is made.

### Platform

Stack.JS will run on all major browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari). Currently, I am running the tests in Chrome.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

The code is located at http://launchpad.net/stackjs. You can check it out using Bazaar by running these commands in an empty directory:

```
bzr init
bzr pull lp:stackjs
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I would implement using this library code to get all the three-letter tags on a site.

Comment: @hippietrail: Here is an example using the latest code in `trunk`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/815630/

Comment: Is there a URL where we can "include" the latest version in a script tag, like jQuery has? And the same for a minified version?

Comment: @hippietrail: not yet, though that is planned. In the meantime, feel free to use this: http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/stack.min.js Keep in mind that the library is still in its early stages.

Comment: I just tried running it in jsfiddle and after some time I got my first ever API error! `{"error_id":502, "error_name":"throttle_violation", "error_message":"too many requests from this IP"}`

Comment: @hippietrail: Hmm... sounds like the request throttling needs some more work. **Edit:** okay, I've made some adjustments. Please try it again.

Comment: Had to wait for my ban to expire. Same problem still though! It seems you're not setting a page size, which could be up to 100.

Comment: @hippietrail: That's very strange. I will look into this and let you know when this gets  resolved.

Comment: OK that problem seems to be solved. But now I can't figure out how to get the list of all 3-letter tag synonyms. The obvious way of just chaning `Tags` in the code to `Synonyms` didn't work and I couldn't find much useful documentation other than the source code.

Comment: Does this library (still) work? Can anyone provide a jsfiddle or some examples?

Comment: @foo I don't think it does. It was never updated for the latest version of the API.