# Stack.PY - A Python Module for Accessing the Stack Exchange 2.1 API

Tags: library, python

> ### Now on PyPI!
>
> You can now find [Stack.PY on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stackpy), Python's package index. This means that you can install the package simply by running the following command in a terminal:
>
> ```
> pip install stackpy
> ```

[image]

### About

Stack.PY is based heavily on [Stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/q/826) and [Stack.JS](https://stackapps.com/q/2988), taking the chained-method concept and applying it to Python. The end result is an *extremely* easy to use module, named `stackpy`:

```
from stackpy import API, Site

# Print the names of all Stack Exchange sites
for site in API.sites:
    print(site['name'])

# Grab the first question on Stack Overflow
print(Site('stackoverflow').questions[0].title)
```

Here are some of the other features you can expect from Stack.PY:

- **Caching:** currently Stack.PY ships with an SQLite database backend (used for caching currently). By default, if no cache is set, Stack.PY creates an in-memory SQLite database to cache requests for the current session.
- **Full documentation:** using a single command (see the `README` file) you can generate all of the documentation for the entire module - including an explanation for each parameter of every method.

Many more features are planned:

- A test suite.
- A series of examples (currently there is one really primitive example).
- Full support for rate-limiting and the `backoff` response.

Stack.PY should run perfectly fine in Python 3k using `2to3`.

#### License

Stack.PY is released under the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT).

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

The code for Stack.PY is hosted [here on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/stackpy). You can check out the latest code using:

```
bzr init
bzr pull lp:stackpy
```

You can view the code online [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Egeorge-edison55/stackpy/trunk/files).

Stack.PY uses `distutils` so you can install the module by running:

```
python setup.py install
```

...**or**... if you are using Ubuntu, you can add [my PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Egeorge-edison55/+archive/george-edison) and install the appropriate package:

`sudo apt-get install python-stackpy` (for Python 2k)
`sudo apt-get install python3-stackpy` (for Python 3k)

Comment: nice work! But can you tell how to make a API.begin_explicit call? I can't find an example of this.

Comment: @Thomas15v: I've added an explanation and example in an answer below.

Comment: Can you add a better explanation of what this can do?

Comment: @Cody: Do you mean more code examples?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what this does

Comment: How do I use the [/users/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) call? The [example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stackpy/trunk/view/head:/examples/src/users.py) shows how to pass an ID, but after a user logs in all I've got in the `access_token`, which `me` uses to return a user.

Comment: @Andy: Good question. How this is _supposed_ to work is that you call `some_se_site.users.me.access_token('12345')`. Unfortunately, the `me` attribute is mysteriously missing from the source code. I am planning to rewrite this library within the next couple of months, so I will make sure this is added to the list of things to fix.

Comment: can I access Stack Overflow data in real time using this API ?

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan: Yes, please see the documentation here: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events

Comment: Where/How to set `_ttl=None` and disable caching altogether?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't touched the code for this in years. I don't think there was ever a way to adjust `_ttl`, sadly.

Answer (score 4):

### Example of Explicit Authentication:

Explicit authentication is relatively straightforward with Stack.PY. Assuming you have already [registered your application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register), the instructions look something like this:

1. Visit your [application's page](https://stackapps.com/questions/3841/how-to-access-my-app-info) to obtain the following information:

   - key
   - client ID
   - client secret
2. Provide Stack.PY with the above information:

   ```
   from stackpy import API

   # Fill in the strings with the appropriate values:
   API.key, API.client_id, API.client_secret = "", "", ""
   ```
3. The `API.begin_explicit()` call consists of the following parameters:

   - a string consisting of the required privileges separated by commas
   - the URI to redirect the user to when the authorization completes
   - an optional string value to be returned with the access token when authorization completes

   Example:

   ```
   redirect_uri = API.begin_explicit('read_inbox,no_expiry',
                                     'http://example.com/done')
   ```

   The return value of the function is the URL that you will need to redirect the user to. That page will allow the user to authorize your application.
4. The `API.complete_explicit()` call consists of the following parameters:

   - the value of the GET parameter `code`
   - the URI you provided to `begin_explicit()` above

   Example:

   ```
   access_token = API.complete_explicit(request.GET['code'],
                                        'http://example.com/done')
   ```

   The return value is the access token for the user.

Comment: On this line, access_token = API.complete_explicit(request.GET['code'], 'http://example.com/done'), I am getting an error - Name error: name 'request' is not defined. Why?

Comment: @lifebalance: That was an example using Django. You will need to use whatever web framework you are using to get the value of the 'code' GET parameter.

Answer (score 3):

## Example - Downloading a question with its body

```
from stackpy import Site

site = Site('stackoverflow')
question = site.questions(1732348).filter('withbody')[0]

print '--- %s ---' % question.title
print question.body
```

Comment: Actually, printing a question will print the title by default. So you can do: `print question` instead of `print question.title`.

Answer (score 2):

### Question: How do you request all Tags?

Retrieving a list of tags on a given Stack Exchange site with Stack.PY is relatively straightforward:

```
from stackpy import Site

sa = Site('stackapps')
for t in sa.tags:
    print t
```

However, this will only fetch the first 30 tags. The tricky part is fetching more than one page. You can fetch any particular page by sticking `.page(n)` on the end of the request chain (where *`n`* is the page to fetch).

If we rewrite the loop a bit, we end up with:

```
from itertools import count
from stackpy import Site

sa = Site('stackapps')
for p in count(1):
    tags = sa.tags.page(p)
    for t in tags:
        print t
    if not tags['has_more']:
        break
```

The example above uses a generator that will yield an infinite list of consecutive page numbers to fetch all of the pages. When the `has_more` property is set to `false` in the JSON returned by the API, the loop will terminate.

Comment: I've edited your answer into a question / answer combo. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know, offhand, how complete this library is? Are there parts of the StackExchange API v2.1 that you *know* are not covered yet?

Comment: As a server-side library, Stack.PY does not cover implicit auth. Pretty much everything else is fully accessible through the library.

Comment: @NathanOsman As a follow up, has this been maintained to support the ability to add content to SE (questions, answers, flags, etc) from version 2.2?

Comment: @Andy: in theory, it should. I'm using the ask question method on my own website. I haven't done a lot of testing, however.

Comment: @NathanOsman, could you post a short snippet of how that works? I am attempting to a.) get available flag options and then b.) send a flag, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to call to get the available options.

Answer (score 1):

After I installed stackpy, how can I get the docs? I installed doxygen but cannot get Stackpy documentation. Can somebody help me?
   In fact, I want to know how to search StackOverflow for related questions in my own QA site using your StackExchange API app.

Many thanks.

Comment: Quote: "**Full documentation**: using a single command (see the README file) you can generate all of the documentation for the entire module - including an explanation for each parameter of every method.". Is that inaccurate?

Comment: @Mat that documentation looks nice, but doesn't actually tell **anything** (beyond the names of classes, and their `__str__`, `__init__` etc. members)

Comment: I tried with doxygen in windows and it´s necessary a configuration file that i don´t know where is it

Answer (score 1):

My actual requirement is to find the answers to question with specified tags. That is given a tag I want to get answers to questions with those tag. I am hoping when I get the tag I will get the time of answering as well. How can I do that. More over I am getting the below error. Can anyone help me with this.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ANI\workspace\StackOverFlow\src\Pydev.py", line 28, in <module>
    question = sa.answers(ans)[0]
  File "C:\Users\ANI\Anaconda-1.9.2\lib\site-packages\stackpy\request.py", line 135, in __getitem__
    return self._fetch()['items'][index] if type(index) == int else self._fetch()[index]
  File "C:\Users\ANI\Anaconda-1.9.2\lib\site-packages\stackpy\request.py", line 157, in _fetch
    self._data = self._url.fetch()
  File "C:\Users\ANI\Anaconda-1.9.2\lib\site-packages\stackpy\url.py", line 87, in fetch
    raise APIError(data['error_id'], data['error_message'])
stackpy.url.APIError: API error 502: too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 84392 seconds.
```

Comment: The error you're receiving is caused by exceeding the daily request quota. If you are not using an API key, I would suggest registering for one since it greatly increases the daily limit. If you are using a key, then you will need to contact Stack Exchange to request an increased limit on your key.