# StackIRC - Posting Questions from Stack Exchange Sites to IRC Channels

Tags: app, python

### Screenshot

http://static.quickmediasolutions.com/media/screenshots/irc.png

### About

Similar to the Twitter feeds for each Stack Exchange site, this small IRC bot retrieves questions from any Stack Exchange site and regularly posts them to an IRC channel of your choice. The bot offers quite a few configurable settings and is capable of posting questions from multiple tags to multiple channels.

#### License

StackIRC is released under the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT).

### Code

The code for StackIRC can be found here:
https://github.com/nathan-osman/StackIRC

That page also contains installation instructions for Ubuntu users (though the application will run unmodified on other platforms).

The application is written in Python and uses [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) for connecting to IRC networks and [Stack.PY](https://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api) for accessing the Stack Exchange API.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

Comment: Also... if someone can come up with something to replace my [really crumby logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ltRiV.png) that would be awesome :)