# How to access my App info

Tags: support, api, api-key, registration

I've registered for an app yesterday, but I'm not finding where should I go to see/edit its info again.
I've search through profile, at stackexchange.com but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the page listing all of your v2.0 and v2.1 keys here:

> https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth

Comment: good, but where can i find a link to it? (maybe in profile)?

Comment: @loldop: A link to it?

Comment: yes, link. where i can found link?

Comment: @loldop: Any v2.0 and v2.1 application that you've created will show up on the above linked page.