# Overwhelmed by unorganized information

Tags: support, api

As you can see I am a newbie, and trying to use Stack Exchange API for a school project.

I spent 3 hours just trying to understand How to get started. Is there an example for me to follow? or **A** document that I can read rather than jumping back and forth between information in Question Answer format? I am using JavaScript to call the Stack Exchange API.

Comment: [I've written a relatively simple introduction here.](http://stackapps.com/questions/3845/software-for-javascript/3849#3849)

Comment: And you're aware of [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), right?