# Stack Posts WordPress Widget

Tags: app, wordpress

### Screenshot

[image: widget configuration and result]

### About

Plugin to show the recent or historic activity widget from a specific user, or generic for the whole site. Enter a user ID and select the site. The random mode is great to discover what's going on the network.

#### License

Released under the [GPLv2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

#### Download

http://wordpress.org/plugins/stack-exchange-posts-widget/

#### Platform

WordPress plugin. Requires WP 3.3+.

### Contact

Author: [Rodolfo Buaiz](http://stackexchange.com/users/1211516?tab=accounts).
Please, use WordPress forums for technical feedback and bug reports.

### Code

After hanging around at [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), one learns a lot in plugin development. Special thanks to the austro-german wing, kaiser and toscho.
And, surely enough, Stack Overflow for all the PHP/CSS/jQuery needs a programmer may have.

#### Acknowledgments

- Stack Exchange API library: [StackPHP](https://stackapps.com/q/826/10590)
- Dropdown with icons: [Image dropdown](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown), by Marghoob Suleman.

> <sup>**Changelog**
>
>   *Version 1.0*
>
>    - Plugin launch.</sup>