# How do I make sure my access_token gets passed?

Tags: support, api, stack.php

I am authenticating via the explicit method, but I still get a 502 throttling error. Is my key not getting passed?

Do I need to pass the access_token with the request? if so. How do I do that.

I am using PHP, and [Stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/q/826/7653), for a web based application. my current calls are go something like this:

```
$question = $site->Search($query)->SortByVotes()->Filter('!9f8L76x)_');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

figured it out.

api.php has a field 'key' in it. It's not well advertised since a lot of the documentation focuses around the pure api, but after you register, just put you key into that tha variable and conduct your searches the way you normally would and stackphp will take care of the rest.

Comment: How exactly did you set it? How do you know it's being used?